# Conditional .gitignore based on origin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, deployment, heroku

I have an application that I want to host on Heroku. It has sensitive database information that I don't want pushed into the public repo on github... However, I can't add it to the gitignore file, because then it won't get pushed to heroku.

Is it possible to have a conditional gitignore, where I ignore that YML file in origin, but not heroku?

Comment: Depending on the nature and amount of the information in question, an alternative could be to use environment variable. Have a look at the [Heroku docs on config vars](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  Git doesn't support that feature, so you are probably out of luck.  There are various ways to get local-only ignore files in different repositories (`.git/info/exclude`), or on different machines (global ignore), but nothing on a per-origin basis.

The easiest work-around might be to have a "public" branch that has that file deleted, and a pre-commit hook to ensure that the public branch never accepted a commit that added it.

No assurances that won't ever leak the blob to the public copy, however.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [Heroku db:push](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/taps)

I've used that to synch data and you can still ignore all db info.